# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Android & Deeplearning4j dl4j

Tags: android, deep-learning, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I started to work with deeplearning4j in Android, but I have a problem that i t had no solution in recent days.

When I define the neural network, I don't find any problem related to lack of classes or anything similar.

```
        DenseLayer inputLayer = new DenseLayer.Builder()
                .nIn(n_inputs)
                .nOut(45)
                .name("Input")
                .build();

        DenseLayer hiddenLayer = new DenseLayer.Builder()
                .nIn(45)
                .nOut(45)
                .name("Hidden")
                .build();

        OutputLayer outputLayer = new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                .nIn(45)
                .nOut(n_outputs)
                .name("Output")
                .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                .build();

        NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder nncBuilder = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder();
```

However, when I run my application, I encounter an error of the type java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and java.lang.RuntimeException. The class is recognized when developing the code, but not after compiling. The problem is in line of OutputLayer definition.

```
2019-10-04 09:06:28.404 15477-15554/com.example.behavioursim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.behavioursim, PID: 15477
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/nd4j/linalg/lossfunctions/LossFunctions$LossFunction;
        at com.example.behavioursim.ia.BehaviourNeuralNetwork.createNetwork(BehaviourNeuralNetwork.java:122)
        at com.example.behavioursim.ia.BehaviourNeuralNetwork.generateModel(BehaviourNeuralNetwork.java:73)
        at com.example.behavioursim.ui.simulacion.SimulacionFragment$InitModelTask.doInBackground(SimulacionFragment.java:255)
        at com.example.behavioursim.ui.simulacion.SimulacionFragment$InitModelTask.doInBackground(SimulacionFragment.java:247)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions$LossFunction" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.behavioursim-98U7cM9-8aCsBoLJTZm2Wg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.behavioursim-98U7cM9-8aCsBoLJTZm2Wg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.behavioursim-98U7cM9-8aCsBoLJTZm2Wg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.example.behavioursim.ia.BehaviourNeuralNetwork.createNetwork(BehaviourNeuralNetwork.java:122) 
        at com.example.behavioursim.ia.BehaviourNeuralNetwork.generateModel(BehaviourNeuralNetwork.java:73) 
        at com.example.behavioursim.ui.simulacion.SimulacionFragment$InitModelTask.doInBackground(SimulacionFragment.java:255) 
        at com.example.behavioursim.ui.simulacion.SimulacionFragment$InitModelTask.doInBackground(SimulacionFragment.java:247) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2019-10-04 09:06:28.497 15477-15554/com.example.behavioursim I/Process: Sending s
```

This is my gradle file (the gradle plugin is version 3.5.1, but I've tried several versions and it still doesn't work):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.behavioursim"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildToolsVersion = '29.0.2'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
    //implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow:1.14.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    //for retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'



    //OPTION 3
    implementation (group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version: '1.0.0-beta5') {
        exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'opencv-platform'
        exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'leptonica-platform'
        exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'hdf5-platform'
        exclude group: 'org.nd4j', module: 'nd4j-base64'
    }

    implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta5'
    implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta5', classifier: "android-arm"
    implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta5', classifier: "android-arm64"
    implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta5', classifier: "android-x86"
    implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta5', classifier: "android-x86_64"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.6-1.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.6-1.5.1', classifier: "android-arm"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.6-1.5.1', classifier: "android-arm64"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.6-1.5.1', classifier: "android-x86"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.6-1.5.1', classifier: "android-x86_64"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.0-1.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.0-1.5.1', classifier: "android-arm"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.0-1.5.1', classifier: "android-arm64"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.0-1.5.1', classifier: "android-x86"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.0-1.5.1', classifier: "android-x86_64"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.78.0-1.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.78.0-1.5.1', classifier: "android-arm"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.78.0-1.5.1', classifier: "android-arm64"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.78.0-1.5.1', classifier: "android-x86"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.78.0-1.5.1', classifier: "android-x86_64"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
}
```